# How to make discord bot to give out a random number between -100 and 100

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

So as the title I want to make discord bot to give out a random number between -100 and 100 but I don't know how to do it , the bot only can give out a random number in -100 or 100. This is my code:

`if(command.endsWith("random number")) {message.channel.send(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + "%")`

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this:

```
if(command.endsWith("random number")) 
{

message.channel.send(Math.floor((Math.random() - 0.5) * 200) + "%")

}
```

Comment: you mean make a new code or put this next to my code

Comment: Just add this in your code and it will return you numbers in negatives as well as in positives. Just replace "message.channel" line with the line in answer.

Comment: is this code only give out random number between -50 and 50 because no number above 50 appears

Comment: I just updated the code in answer my bad, now check you will get the intended one.